# How to draw a decomposition and composition for a method?

Tags: java, recursion, composition, decomposition

Consider the following code fragment

```
public int fun(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 1)
        return a;
    else
        return a + fun(a, b - 1);
}
```

a.  Draw the decomposition & composition of  fun(2,4)

b.  What would be the value of fun(2,0)?Discuss and show a screenshot that proves your answer.

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL5u3.png)

Comment: Please don't paste images of your code and errors. Instead, edit your question by adding both as properly formatted code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a. Draw the decomposition & composition of fun(2,4)

Your question sounds like a homework task and I don't want to do the work for you.

That said, I can draw the decomposition/composition diagram for another example to give you an idea.

Here's a diagram for `fun(0,3)`:

[image: Decomposition/composition diagram]

where **black** arrows indicate the *decomposition* and **blue** arrows the *composition* of `fun(0,3)`.

The decomposition procedure (**black**):

1. Draw `fun(0, 3)`
2. By examining your code, you can see that in order to compute `fun(0, 3)`, you first have to compute `fun(0, 2)`, so you draw `fun(0, 2)`
3. In order to compute `fun(0, 2)`, you first have to compute `fun(0, 1)`, so you draw `fun(0, 1)`

The composition procedure (**blue**):

1. `fun(0, 1)` returns `a`, or in your case `0`
2. You can now compute `fun(0, 2) = a + fun(0, 1) = 0 + 0 = 0`
3. And finally, you can compute `fun(0, 3) = a + fun(0, 2) = 0 + 0 = 0`

---

> b. What would be the value of fun(2,0)?Discuss and show a screenshot
> that proves your answer.

As you've seen, that particular case produces a `StackOverflow` error. If you tried drawing a decomposition/composition diagram for that case, you'd end up with a single, endless branch.